# any option to make the graph area shrink when a drop down button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, rickshaw

I am working of d3 as well as with rickshaw.js. i have made the graph and the legend in a single container. so when the legend drop down is clicked it slides down. i am trying to shrink the graph area when the drop down slides down. as well as when the drop down slides up, the graph has to regain its original structure.any help or suggestions. as i even tried with the example with i have fiddled it. does not seemed to work.http://jsfiddle.net/YrhF3/1/   . thanks in advance

Here is my fiddled code:

```
         $(function()
    {
      var expanded = false;
       $('.dropdownlegend').click(function(){
      if (!expanded)
        {

          $('.scatterchart').animate({width:'30%'}, 400);
          expanded = true;
      }
      else
      {

            $('scatterchart').animate({width:'59%'}, 400);
            expanded = false;
           }
            });
           });
```

Comment: your code is working for me

Comment: yeah, seems to work fine. Check it again.

Comment: it works fine when the legend is outside the container. but does not when it is inside.

Comment: is the legend "steam"?  because that seems to be inside you container and it's working fine in the fiddle.